# How to use DatePicker in MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I table tblEmp stucture like this :

```
Id          int
Name    nvarchar
NIK         int
Point   numeric
JointDate   date
```

and i want field jointDate inputed with datepicker control, so it can input by type the date or i can choose from date component popup, how to do it ?

here is **code in createEmp.cshtml** :

```
@model i_insurance.Models.EmpModel.Emp

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create New Employee";
}

<h2>Create User</h2>

@*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NIK)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NIK)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NIK)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Point)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Point)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Point)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JointDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JointDate, new { @class = "datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JointDate)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure [`jQuery UI datepicker`](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JointDate, new{@class="date-picker"})
```

Then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.date-picker').datepicker();
});
```

Or

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.JointDate,"DateTimeEditor")
```

***DateTimeEditor.cshtml***

```
@model DateTime?
@{
String modelValue = "";
if (Model.HasValue)
 {
    if (Model.Value != DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        modelValue = Model.Value.ToShortDateString();
    }
 }
}

@Html.TextBox("", modelValue, new { @class = "date-picker"})
```

Comment: By default won't TextBoxFor assign `id="JoinDate` and `name="JoinDate"` to the generated control? In which case `$('#JoinDate').datepicker();` would do.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, Updated based on class name :)

Comment: I wasn't saying you were wrong, only suggesting you may not need to set any attributes at all :)

Comment: where i put the code ?

`$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});`

in createEmp.cshtml ? and in what section ..
did i need to add source jquery ?

Comment: @DeddyH, If you use only in one page, you can add it in the page and make sure you are adding the necessary script files includes jquery, jquryui & css. If you want many places add it in layout page